# Где стоит хранить данные о рекордах в оффлайн игре

Tags: java, android, база-данных

Создается текстовый документ или какой-то другой документ ? и пожалуйста напиши код, который  создает этот документ и производит запись в него, а так же считывание. Допустим, что храним не много результатов. и без кода на словах опишите вариант, если бы надо было хранить много данных, как бы следовало реализовывать

Comment: Можете в текстовом виде их хранить, можете в бинарном. Можете шифровать данные, можете не шифровать. Можете в файле их хранить, можете в БД. Смотря что вам нужно и что удобнее.

Comment: Ну в общем , это достаточный ответ, просто хотел убедиться не используют ли ничего специфического .А как записать в каком виде и как считывать я думаю смогу найти в гугл.

Comment: Да, примеров в интернете предостаточно на все варианты. Главное определиться с комбинацией.

Comment: Под комбинацией вы имеете ввиду вариант шифровки?

Comment: Нет, имею в виду выбор из каждой пары "текстовый/бинарный" + "шифр./нешифр." + "файл/БД". Это получается 8 комбинаций. А, возможно, я упустил ещё какой-то параметр.

Answer (score 1):

Не нужно хранить данные в SharedPreferences, так как их легко изменить с пут правами. 
Можно создать небольшую базу данных, или шифровать в файл, так вы сможете избежать изменения файлов из вне

Comment: Стоит ли создавать небольшую базу данных , если намереваюсь хранить всего 10 последних рекордов?  Чем шифровать, чтобы не слишком долгая процедура, какой алгоритм достаточен для этого дела?

Comment: @Turalllb я немного старался с телефоном когда получил рут права, и могу с уверенностью сказать что главное не хранить их в SharedPreferences, так как они слишком легкодоступны, ну а метод решения тебе самому выбирать, можно просто небольшой шифр самому написать, например со сдвигом алфавита и записывать в файл. Но если хочешь продавать, например, игровую валюту, то не храни ее количеств в XML файлах(SharedPreferences)

Comment: А разве база данных или запись в файл не так же легкодоступны? root правами можно менять вроде любые системные файлы. А что собой представляет база данных , её можно наверно будет открыть и изменить. Файл тоже можно изменить, то так как он зашифрован, непонятно будет что мы изменили. И вот встает вопрос, а нельзя ли данные в базе данных записывать шифруя? Это наверно самый удобный способ. Потому что с текстовым файлом работать сложнее, определять Новый ли это рекорд, да и доступ к данным в базе данных быстрее, если речь идет о большом количестве рекордов.

Comment: В SharedPreferences  так же можно записывать уже шифрованные данные , изменить их конечно можно будет, если имеется root, но что изменили не ясно. Текстовый файл думаю неудобен, остается выбор между базой данных и SharedPreferences. Для не крупных задач наверно SharedPreferences .

Comment: Это же оффлайновая игра. Ну получит пользователь рут-доступ, ну накрутит себе циферки. От этого же не будет вреда никому. Значит и защищать информацию вроде бы не нужно.